# Grab img tag under a link with a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a img that I need to change and I can't access the html right now so need to do it with just css

The structure is

```
<a href="afd.com" class="imgfile">
  <img src = "adsfasd">
</a>
```

I need to change the src of the img, but I'm not sure how to grab it.  I tried 'grab element by selector' in chrome but that's not working exactly.

Once I grab it I'll just do something like

```
var image = document.querySelector(".example");
image.src = "image1.jpg"
```

Note, NO jquery

Comment: I see no CSS class `example` in the HTML you showed. *so need to do it with just css*  but shows no CSS but Javascript solution. Totally unclear what you are trying to do and what your requirements are - what you say and what you show contradict.

Comment: use JS: `document.querySelector(".imgfile img").src = "image1.jpg";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select just like CSS in `querySelector`

```js
const image = document.querySelector("a.imgfile img");
image.src = "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x150";
```

```html
<a href="afd.com" class="imgfile">
  <img src="adsfasd" />
</a>
```